# C# - Passing View to the converter as parameter

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, converters

I have a **view** with couple of **data templates** in the **resources** of that view. *(I don't want to put it somewhere global since its only needed by this particular view)*

Based on value I get in converter I switch the template.

```
public class SplitTemplateSelector : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int splitCount = (int)value;
            var _view = new IdtDetailView();

            DataTemplate template;
            if (splitCount == 1)
            {
                //(DataTemplate)_view.Resources["SingleSplitTemplate"];
                template = (DataTemplate)_view.Resources.Where(w => w.Key.Equals("SingleSplitTemplate")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
            }
            else
            {
                template = (DataTemplate)_view.Resources.Where(w => w.Key.Equals("MultiSplitTemplate")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
            }

            return template;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

This works as intended, however because I instantiate new `IdtDetailView()`, I run into some problems where variables aren't set-up properly etc. Therefore my question is...

**How do I pass or access view which called this converter so that I don't have to create new IdtDetailView?**

Comment: Also note that I'm using Keys to find data template because if I just used name, the second time I would call this converter SL would complain that data template with following name already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest next solution:

```
 public class SplitTemplateSelector : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SingleSplitTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SingleSplitTemplate",
                                        typeof (DataTemplate),
                                        typeof(SplitTemplateSelector),
                                        null);

        public DataTemplate SingleSplitTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(SingleSplitTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SingleSplitTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MultiSplitTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MultiSplitTemplate",
                                        typeof (DataTemplate),
                                        typeof(SplitTemplateSelector),
                                        null);

        public DataTemplate MultiSplitTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(MultiSplitTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MultiSplitTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int splitCount = (int)value;
            return splitCount == 1 ? SingleSplitTemplate : MultiSplitTemplate;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

    }
```

In XAML:

```
<c:SplitTemplateSelector x:Key="SplitTemplateSelector" SingleSplitTemplate="{StaticResource SingleSplitTemplate}" MultiSplitTemplate="{StaticResource MultiSplitTemplate}"/>
```

As you understand, you can put converter near local data templates in user control resources

Comment: As always the answer was right in the middle. I needed a hybrid between datatemplate selector and converter.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need some kind of [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).
Unfortunately, this class only exists in WPF but you can find some alternative implementations on the web. 
For example:
http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/entryid/1404/Silverlight-a-port-of-the-DataTemplateSelector.aspx

The idea is to have a content control that has an array of data templates. The selection of the displayed content is based on a value (in your case it's an integer).

Comment: I have managed to implement DataTemplateSelector from Telerik, however now I'm unable to get the Count property of the ItemsSource, since my selection is based on amount of rows in my observable collection. Any ideas?